# Error in CognitiveServices Speech with Blazor server on Azure Linux App Service

Tags: linux, blazor, azure-cognitive-services

After installing the Blazor App on App service (Linux and .net 6.0) everything works fine, except the CognitiveServices.

The code throws an exception in de constructor of SpeechRecognizer:

```
SpeechConfig speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("<key>", "<region>");
AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
  
var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
_recognizer.Recognized += Recognizer_Recognized;
```

> error: System.ApplicationException: Exception with an error code: 0x38
> (SPXERR_AUDIO_SYS_LIBRARY_NOT_FOUND)    at
> Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.SpxExceptionThrower.ThrowIfFail(IntPtr
> hr)    at
> Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Recognizer.FromConfig(GetRecognizerFromConfigDelegate
> fromConfig, SpeechConfig speechConfig, AudioConfig audioConfig)    at
> Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechRecognizer..ctor(SpeechConfig
> speechConfig, AudioConfig audioConfig)

The code runs fine locally from Visual Studio 2022 (of course).

The installation packages shows the necessary dll/so files

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/517

"Azure App Service runs on servers in the cloud. Those servers don't have microphones (since the microphones would be somewhere in the datacetner were customers can't physically go). If you wish to create a web app for your customers to use the microphone from the browser/web, you should use the javascript version of the SDK, and embedd that js code into your web page."